# lighttpd access.log appeng with prefix hostname like hostname-access.log

Tags: linux, lighttpd

We have multiple severs behind loadbalncer and we want access log of each machines in way that it access prefix as hosname with accesslog in lighttpd.

For example :

`192.168.1.1-access.log`
`192.168.1.2-access.log`

I tried to use `include_shell` parameter and have a script with `hostname.sh`, but its not serving my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could be trying to over complicate this problem, could you not just do the following?

```
$SERVER["socket"] == “192.168.1.1:80″ {
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/192.168.1.1-access.log"
}
```

You also mentioned you were having trouble with include_shell try the following

*lighttpd.conf*

```
include_shell "/etc/lighttpd/scripts/servername.sh"
accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/" + var.servername  + "-access.log"
```

*scripts/servername.sh* - for hostname

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'var.servername="'$(uname -n)'"'
```

*OR*

*scripts/servername.sh* - for ip address

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'var.servername="'$(/sbin/ifconfig | sed -n '2 p' | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/addr://g)'"'
```

(change the sed and awk param to get the right IP for your on more than one interface)

This will give you what you are looking for.

Alternatively just cat `accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/" +`uname -n`+ "-access.log"` to the end of the config file for a cheap and dirty solution.

Comment: I have 200 machine behind load balancer, with n number of virtual hosts.

Comment: I've added a more complete answer to the question. If this still isn't fit for purpose you could write a script to rename the files as they are downloaded/collected from the respective server.